# Exclude jar-with-dependencies from deploying to Nexus

Tags: maven, maven-shade-plugin

I'm using [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) to create an additional jar with all my dependencies. The shade phase is linked to the package phase, so my jar-with-dependencies is created everytime I do a `mvn package`.

However, I do not want this jar-with-dependencies to be deployed to Nexus during `mvn deploy`. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Why are you creating a supplemental artifact via maven-shade but don't like to get it deployed ?

Comment: We need it during runtime. Like you suggested, a _runtime_ profile might be the right thing to do. Let me try it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution for such purpose is to put the maven-shade-plugin configuration into a profile which is not activated during the deploy phase.

Comment: Could you give an example how that would look like?

Comment: I want actually the same but inverted: I want to *exclude* certain dependencies on deploy.

Answer (score 2):

Driven by the same necessity I've forked the **maven-deploy-plugin** plugin from GitHub doing changes in order to exclude a specific attached artifact from deploy as follow:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <configuration>
    <skipAttachedArtifacts>
      <artifact>
        <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
        <artifactId>something</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <classifier>shaded</classifier>
      </artifact>
    </skipAttachedArtifacts>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

> Currently using the **maven-deploy-plugin** plugin with *skip* parameter set to true all artifacts are excluded from deploy while target here is to exclude only a specific one from the attached ones. On my fork I've introduced the **skipAttachedArtifacts** configuration parameter in order to specify attached artifacts to exclude from deploy.

Here is the link on my forked project on GitHub:
https://github.com/gregorycallea/maven-deploy-plugin

Here the link instead to the pull request I've submitted on apache plugin project:
https://github.com/apache/maven-deploy-plugin/pull/3